# Magento2: Open new window on button onclick

Tags: magento2, javascript

I have added a new button to order view action buttons:

```
class ReturnButton
{
    public function beforePushButtons(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\Toolbar\Interceptor $subject,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\ButtonList $buttonList
    ) {

        $this->_request = $context->getRequest();
        if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'sales_order_view'){
              $buttonList->add(
                'returnButton',
                ['label' => __('New return request'), 'onclick' => 'setLocation(\'http://foo.bar\')', 'class' => 'reset'],
                1
            );
        }

    }
}
```

However, I would need to open a new window, setLocation naturally sets new location for current window. What is the correct way to do this in Magento 2?

Answer (score 4):

Substitute `'setLocation(\'http://foo.bar\')'`  with `'window.open(\'http://foo.bar\')'`

That *should* do it.

Comment: It does. Maybe I'll just settle with this, in case there is no Magento funtion for this.